# Is there a way to solve an I/O error 6 in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

```pascal
procedure TfrmSongs.Display;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  redOutput.Clear;
  redOutput.Lines.Add('The TOP 10');
  for i := 1 to iCount-1 do
  begin
    redOutput.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i)+arrSongs[i]);
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmSongs.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  tSongList: TextFile;
  sSong: string;
begin
  iCount := 0;
  AssignFile(tSongList, ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'Songs.txt');
  Reset(tSongList);
  while not EOF do
  begin
    Readln(tSongList, sSong);
    arrSongs[iCount] := sSong;
    Inc(iCount);
  end;
  CloseFile(tSongList);
  Display;
end;
```

I'm trying to display the array I tried to create via a text file in a rich edit. But every time I run the app, it gives me an 'I/O error 6' error and nothing displays. I don't know if it's something with the text file or if it's something with the display procedure.

Comment: Make life easier for yourself. Use just one version of Delphi rather than two. And stop using legacy file I/O. Use a string list to read a text file. Or a reader class. Also, do consider learning how to debug. Make it your goal to be able to debug. Life as a programmer is pretty much impossible until you learn that.

Comment: ...or `TFile.ReadAllLines`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan We only had a short chapter on debugging last year (about 3 pages long?) but I'd love to learn how to debug in Delphi. Cause sometimes I just wanna punch my screen over debugging errors.

Comment: @Dragon: Put a breakpoint on the `begin` line in `FormActivate`. You can do that by pressing F5 while on that line or by clicking the ruler. Then run your application (F9). You will see that you end up in the editor when it is time to run `FormActivate`. Then press `F8` to run one line at a time. Had you done this, you would easily have found that the problem is on the `while not EOF do` line.

Comment: I always think it is best to learn how to debug without using an IDE. Add lots of `writeln` statements and use them to work out the path of execution through the program (trace debugging). Use them to inspect intermediate values. In due course do the same with the IDE, but you need to know trace debugging no matter what because there will be times when you can't use a debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code, but regarding the I/O error specifically, error 6 means "invalid file handle".

Since you are getting a popup error notification, you clearly have [I/O checking](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Input_output_checking_(Delphi)) enabled, which it is by default.

I/O error 6 is not typical for a failure on [`System.Reset()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Reset), and you are not seeing any other kind of error related to a failure in opening a file, so we can safely assume that the file is being opened successfully, and that [`System.Readln()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Readln) and [`System.CloseFile()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.CloseFile) are not being passed an invalid I/O handle.

So that leaves just one line that could be receiving an invalid I/O handle:

`while not EOF do`

[`System.Eof()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Eof) has an optional parameter to tell it which file to check. Since you are omitting that parameter, `Eof()` will use [`System.Input`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Input) instead. And a GUI process does not have a STDIN handle assigned by default. So that is likely where error 6 is coming from.

That line needs to be changed to this instead:

`while not EOF(tSongFile) do`

**UPDATE**: given the declaration of `arrSongs` you have shown in comments (`arrSongs: array[1..MAX] of string;`), there are additional problems with your code.  You need to make sure the reading loop does not try to store more than `MAX` strings in the array. Also, your reading loop is trying to store a string at index 0, which is not a valid index since the array starts at index 1. Also, `Display()` is skipping the *last* string in the array.  See what happens when you omit important details?

Try this instead:

```pascal
private
  arrSongs: array[1..MAX] of string;

...

procedure TfrmSongs.Display;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  redOutput.Clear;
  redOutput.Lines.Add('The TOP 10');
  for i := 1 to iCount do
  begin
    redOutput.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i) + arrSongs[i]);
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmSongs.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  tSongList: TextFile;
  sSong: string;
begin
  iCount := 0;
  AssignFile(tSongList, ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Songs.txt');
  Reset(tSongList);
  try
    while (not EOF(tSongList)) and (iCount < MAX) do
    begin
      Readln(tSongList, sSong);
      arrSongs[1+iCount] := sSong;
      Inc(iCount);
    end;
  finally
    CloseFile(tSongList);
  end;
  Display;
end;
```

That being said, I would suggest getting rid of the reading loop completely.  You can use a [`TStringList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStringList) instead:

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.Classes;

...

private
  lstSongs: TStringList;

...

procedure TfrmSongs.Display;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  redOutput.Clear;
  redOutput.Lines.Add('The TOP 10');
  for i := 0 to lstSongs.Count-1 do
  begin
    redOutput.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i+1) + lstSongs[i]);
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmSongs.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lstSongs := TStringList.Create;
end;

procedure TfrmSongs.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lstSongs.Free;
end;

procedure TfrmSongs.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lstSongs.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Songs.txt');
  Display;
end;
```

Or, you can use [`TFile.ReadAllLines()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllLines) instead:

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.IOUtils;

...

private
  arrSongs: TStringDynArray;

...

procedure TfrmSongs.Display;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  redOutput.Clear;
  redOutput.Lines.Add('The TOP 10');
  for i := 0 to High(arrSongs) do
  begin
    redOutput.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i+1) + arrSongs[i]);
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmSongs.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  arrSongs := TFile.ReadAllLines(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Songs.txt');
  Display;
end;
```

Comment: Ok thanks man, I'll try it out. By the way, I'd just like to know what problems my code has?(so I can improve upon my coding ability in future).

Comment: @DragonSentinel You are not allocating `arrSongs` before filling it, unless you are allocating it statically, in which case you are not ensuring the reading loop doesn't exceed the bounds of the array. Also, you are not closing the file if `EOF()` or `Readln()` fails. It would be easier to just get rid of the manual reading loop altogether and just use `TStringList.LoadFromFile()` or `TFile.ReadAllLines()` instead. Also, `Display()` skips the first string in the array, do you really want that?

Comment: Ok, so I changed the line to 'while not EOF(tSongFile) do' but now I get an error that says 'Access violation at address 0040B05E in module frmSongs.exe.Write of address 0AFDEA3C. '.I got those errors in some of the other exercises too, so could you maybe tell me what the absolute hell that error means?

Comment: @DragonSentinel That is likely due to the mishandling of the array that I mentioned earlier. You are not allocating the array correctly, so you are trying to access invalid memory

Comment: When you mean allocating it statically, do you mean something like 'arrSongs: array[1..MAX] of string'?And could you maybe explain to me on how to use these (TStringList.LoadFromFile(),TFile.ReadAllLines() ) please?

Comment: @DragonSentinel Yes, that is what I mean by statically. Given that declaration, you need to make sure the reading loop does not try to store more than `MAX` strings in the array. Also, your reading loop is trying to store a string at index 0, which is not a valid index. Also, `Display` is then skipping the *last* string in the array rather than the *first* string. See what happens when you omit important details like this?